# Braintree Payment Collection Authentication Required Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, payment-gateway, braintree, 3d-secure

We have a custom subscription module and recently due to the new law that has passed in the UK requiring 3D security, the payments are failing due to the payment requiring authentication. If we manually place the order via the backend payment will be taken fine without requiring authentication.

Below is the quote that gathers the payment information and submits the quote. I'd be grateful if anyone could share some advice to overcome the problem. Please do let me know if you'd require any further information.

```
if ($paymentId != 'invoice') {
        $paymentId = str_replace('token-', '', $paymentId);
        
        try {
            //check if customer is credit card or paypal.
            $tokens = $this->paymentTokens->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $orderData['customer_Id'])
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_visible', 1);
                
            //$this->outputService->writeln('#Braintree undefined index debug#');
            foreach ($tokens as $token) {
                
                if($paymentId == $token->getEntityId() || count($tokens) === 1) {
                    
                    $this->outputService->writeln(print_r($token->getPaymentMethodCode(), true));
                    switch($token->getPaymentMethodCode()) {
                        case 'braintree':
                            $data['method'] = 'braintree_cc_vault';
                            break;
                        case 'braintree_paypal':
                            $data['method'] = 'braintree_paypal_vault';
                            $public_hash = $token->getPublicHash();
                            break;
                    }
                    
                    $this->outputService->writeln(print_r($data['method'], true));
                }
            }
            //$this->outputService->writeln('#Braintree undefined index debug end#');
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->outputService->writeln('#Braintree method exception - '.$e->getMessage().'#');
            $this->outputService->writeln($e->getTraceAsString());
            $this->outputService->writeln('#Braintree undefined index debug end#');
        }
        
        // Get public hash for the active credit card for brain tree.
        if($data['method'] == 'braintree_cc_vault') {
        
            #$card = $this->paymentTokenManagement->getByPaymentId($paymentId);
            $cards = $this->paymentTokenManagement->getListByCustomerId($orderData['customer_Id']);
            $card = null;
            //Find active card.
            foreach ($cards as $c) {
                if ($paymentId == 'active-card') {
                    if ($c->getIsActive()) {
                        $card = $c;
                    }
                } else {
                    if ($c->getId() == $paymentId) {
                        $card = $c;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!$card) {
                return   ['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Card was not found'];
            }
            $public_hash = $card->getData('public_hash');
        }


        // Need to pass Customer ID and Store ID below
        try {
            $paymentMethodNonce = $this->command->execute(['public_hash' => $public_hash,
                'customer_id' => $customer->getId(), 'store_id' => $customer->getStoreId()])->get();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            return ['msg' => $e->getMessage()];
        }
        $paymentMethodNonce = $paymentMethodNonce['paymentMethodNonce'];

        $data['public_hash'] = $public_hash;
        $data['payment_method_nonce'] = $paymentMethodNonce;
    }

    if ($method == 'purchaseorder') {
        $data['po_number'] = $orderData['po_number'];
    }
    
    $quote->setInventoryProcessed(true); //not effetc inventory
    $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready

    // Set Sales Order Payment
    $quote->getPayment()->importData($data);
    $quote->setSubscriptionId($orderData['subscription_id']);
    //$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'braintree_cc_vault', 'public_hash' => $public_hash, 'payment_method_nonce' => $paymentMethodNonce));
    try {
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();       
        // Create Order From Quote
        //quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($quote->getId());
        try {
            $this->outputService->writeln('Submitted the quote to order');
            $quote->ignoreMinimumAmount();
            $orderId = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
            $this->outputService->writeln($orderId->getEntityId());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->outputService->writeln($e->getMessage());
            return ['error'=>1,'msg'=>$e->getMessage()];
        }
        $this->outputService->writeln($orderId->getEntityId());
        if (!$orderId) {
            return ['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Error creating order'];
        }
        $order=false;
        try {
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId->getEntityId());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->outputService->writeln($e->getMessage());
        }

        $this->outputService->writeln('before update date');
        if ($order) {
            $this->outputService->writeln('order created');
            $order->setEmailSent(0);
            $order->setCustomerEmail($customer->getEmail());
            $date = new \DateTime($orderData['created_at']);
            $this->outputService->writeln($orderData['created_at']);
            if (isset($orderData['created_at'])) {
                $order->setCreatedAt($orderData['created_at']);
                $order->setUpdatedAt($orderData['created_at']);
            } else {
                $order->setCreatedAt($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $order->setUpdatedAt($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            }
            $order->setSubscriptionId($orderData['subscription_id']);
            $order->save();
            $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
            $result = $order->getEntityId();
        } else {
            $result= ['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->outputService->writeln($e->getMessage());
        $result= ['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with recurring transactions. It was only happening with certain banks. I eventually found this in the documentation that says:

*To override the default behavior of 3DS2 and request the cardholder's bank to issue an authentication challenge, pass challengeRequested: true on the verifyCard() call.*

https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/3d-secure/recurring-transactions#requesting-a-cardholder-challenge

Hope that helps anyone else who encountered the same problem.